# Alter a column based on results from geodistance matrix

Tags: r, geosphere

I've got a dataframe that looks like this:

```
long       lat       site
-141.37    61.13     x1
-149.1833  66.7333   x2
-149.667   67.667    x3
-141.3667  61.1157   x4
```

I want to calculate the distances between all of the `site`'s using `distVincentyEllipsoid`. Then for those sites that are located within 5km distance from each other, I want to modify the `site` name to include both sites. So, in this example `x1` and `x4` are within 5km from each other, so it will  be like this:

```
 long      lat       site  
-141.37    61.13     x1_x4    
-149.1833  66.7333   x2
-149.667   67.667    x3
-141.3667  61.1157   x1_x4
```

I know I can calculate a matrix between all `site`'s in this way:

```
df %>% dplyr::select('long', 'lat')
distm(df, fun = distVincentyEllipsoid)
```

But I don't know how to take it from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is helpful if you provide the example data as R code, like this

```
x <- matrix(c(-141.37, 61.13, -149.1833, 66.7333, -149.667, 67.667, -141.3667, 61.1157), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
colnames(x) <- c("lon", "lat")
x <- data.frame(site=paste0("x", 1:4), x)
```

but thank you for showing the expected output

Solution:

As you suggested, first make a distance matrix. Then classify that as within the threshold distance or not, and then use the rows to select the records. Note that I use `distGeo` --- it is a better method than `distVincentyEllipsoid`.

```
library(geosphere)
m <- distm(x[, c("lon", "lat")], fun=distGeo)

m <- m < 5000
x$name <- apply(m, 1, function(i) paste(x$site[i], collapse="_"))
x
#  site       lon     lat    name
#1   x1 -141.3700 61.1300   x1_x4
#2   x2 -149.1833 66.7333      x2
#3   x3 -149.6670 67.6670      x3
#4   x4 -141.3667 61.1157   x1_x4
```

If you have many points the distance matrix may become too large. In that case you could do

```
y <- x[,  c("lon", "lat")]
for (i in 1:nrow(y)) {
   j <- distGeo(y[i, ], y) < 5000
   x$name[i] <- paste(x$site[j], collapse="_")
}
```

or like this

```
y <- x[,  c("lon", "lat")]
x$name <- x$site    
for (i in 1:nrow(y)) {
   j <- distGeo(y[i, ], y) < 5000
   if (any(j)) {
       x$name[i] <- paste(x$site[j], collapse="_")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one answer using `tidyverse`:

```
library(geosphere)

dist_mat <- distm(select(df, long, lat), fun = distVincentyEllipsoid)


df %>%
  mutate(site_new = map_chr(1:n(), ~paste0(df$site[which(dist_mat[,.x] <= 5000)], collapse = "_")))


# A tibble: 4 x 4
   long   lat site  site_new
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>   
1 -141.  61.1 x1    x1_x4   
2 -149.  66.7 x2    x2      
3 -150.  67.7 x3    x3      
4 -141.  61.1 x4    x1_x4
```